# <class 'UnicodeDecodeError'> that only appears in Python 3 but not Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a project analyzing tweets for an Urban Policy class. The purpose of this script is to parse out certain information from JSON files that a colleague downloaded. Here's a link to a sample Tweet I am trying to parse:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qf1e06601m2mrxr/5thWardChicago.0.json?dl=0

I had a friend of mine test the following script in some version of Python 2 (Windows) and it worked. However, my machine (Windows 10) is running a recent version of Python 3 and its not working for me.

```
import json
import collections
import sys, os
import glob
from datetime import datetime
import csv


def convert(input):
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        return {convert(key): convert(value) for key, value in input.iteritems()}
    elif isinstance(input, list):
        return [convert(element) for element in input]
    elif isinstance(input, unicode):
        return input.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        return input

def to_ilan_csv(json_files):
    # write the column headers
    csv_writer = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w"))
    headers = ["tweet_id", "handle", "username", "tweet_text", "has_image", "image_url", "created_at", "retweets", "hashtags", "mentions", "isRT", "isMT"]
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)

    # open the JSON files we stored and parse them into the CSV file we're working on
    try:
        #json_files = glob.glob(folder)
        print("Parsing %s files." % len(json_files))
        for file in json_files:
            f = open(file, 'r')
            if f != None:
                for line in f:
                    # hack to avoid the trailing \n at the end of the file - sitcking point LH 4/7/16
                    if len(line) > 3:
                        i = 0
                        tweets = convert(json.loads(line))
                        for tweet in tweets:
                            has_media = False
                            is_RT = False
                            is_MT = False
                            hashtags_list = []
                            mentions_list = []
                            media_list = []

                            entities = tweet["entities"]
                            # old tweets don't have key "media" so need a workaround
                            if entities.has_key("media"):
                                has_media = True
                                for item in entities["media"]:
                                    media_list.append(item["media_url"])

                            for hashtag in entities["hashtags"] :
                                hashtags_list.append(hashtag["text"])

                            for user in entities["user_mentions"]:
                                mentions_list.append(user["screen_name"])

                            if tweet["text"][:2] == "RT":
                                is_RT = True

                            if tweet["text"][:2] == "MT":
                                is_MT = True

                            values = [
                                tweet["id_str"],
                                tweet["user"]["id_str"],
                                tweet["user"]["screen_name"],
                                tweet["text"],
                                has_media,
                                ','.join(media_list) if len(media_list) > 0 else "",
                                datetime.strptime(tweet["created_at"], '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                                tweet["retweet_count"],
                                ','.join(hashtags_list) if len(hashtags_list) > 0 else "",
                                ','.join(mentions_list) if len(mentions_list) > 0 else "",
                                is_RT,
                                is_MT
                            ]
                            csv_writer.writerow(values)
                    else:
                        continue
            f.close()

    except:
        print("Something went wrong. Quitting.")
        for i in sys.exc_info():
            print(i)

def parse_tweets():
    
    file_names = []
    file_names.append("C:\\Users\\Adam\\Downloads\\Test Code\\sample1.json")
    file_names.append("C:\\Users\\Adam\\Downloads\\Test Code\\sample2.json")
    to_ilan_csv(file_names)
```

Then I execute by simply performing

```
parse_tweets()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Parsing 2 files.
Something went wrong. Quitting.
<class 'UnicodeDecodeError'>
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 3338: character maps to <undefined>
<traceback object at 0x0000016CCFEE5648>
```

I sought help from a CS friend of mine but he was unable to diagnose the problem. So I've come here.

## MY QUESTION

What is this error and why is it only arising in Python 3 instead of Python 2?

For those who want to try, the code as presented should be able to be run using a Jupyter notebook and the copy of the file in the drop box link I provided.

Comment: Why are you doing the `convert` bit? `csvwriter.writerow` expects strings. There doesn’t seem to be any reason to use bytes here at all.

Comment: Please remove that `try…except` part and then let the program crash naturally. That way, you get a proper stack trace that will tell where exactly the error happened.

Comment: @Ryan Why is that relevant? Backstory, I got this code from a professor who does this and she just turned over the code to me. I hadn't really questioned the structure since I'm inexperienced. But it works in Python 2. Do you think that particular portion could be part of why it is failing in Python 3?

Comment: @poke ok i'll try it

Comment: This code did not work at all in Python 3 for me. I had to change three parts of it due to it using things that are no longer present in Python 3. So I have no idea what you are doing there. That being said, after I fixed those, the program ran without errors. – Are you sure you’re using Python 3 here?

Comment: Alternatively (@poke) use `traceback.print_exc()`.

Comment: @poke 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: @poke if you have a script that works, can I try it? She posted this script 9 months or so ago. It's amazing that Python has changed that much since then. I had no idea coding could become out of date like that.

Comment: Python hasn’t changed that much since 9 months ago. Python 3.0 was released in 2008.

Comment: Well, then I don't understand why there is this issue. Odd.

Comment: No, the issues are there with every Python 3 version: `dict.iteritems()` does not exist, the separate `unicode` type does not exist, and `dict.has_key()` also does not exist. If the code runs for you, then that means that you are not using Python 3 to execute it; try adding a `print(sys.version)` at the top to see what’s actually executing the code.

Comment: Can you show the output of `python -V` from your Windows machine?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid above. but here it is again 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul 5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] –

Comment: The first error you should get is `'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'` if you are running this on Python 3.

Comment: How are you running it exactly?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Jupyter notebook. The error I get is the same one posted in the original question, however I have removed the try, except stuff as requested by previous commenters.

Comment: Would it make sense to download a version of Python 2? Or is this script salvageable?

Comment: You just need to make three changes for it to work in Python3 - but I don't think this script was designed for Python3 in the first place - so better off downloading Python2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133876/discussion-between-stan-shunpike-and-burhan-khalid).

Comment: @StanShunpike Please add a `print(sys.version)` at the top of your script to see what version you are actually executing this with. (btw. for what it’s worth, the script also runs fine for me with Python 2 and your example JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo, after a bit debugging in chat, here’s the solution:

Apparently, the file OP was using was not correctly recognized as UTF-8, so iterating over the file (with `for line in f`) caused the `UnicodeDecodeError` from the `cp1252` encoding module. We fixed that by explicitely opening the file as utf-8:

```
f = open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

After we did that, the file could be opened correctly and OP ran into the Python 3 issues we all have been expecting and seeing before. The following three issues came up:

1. `'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

   `dict.iteritems()` no longer exists in Python 3, so we just switch to `dict.items()` here:

   ```
   return {convert(key): convert(value) for key, value in input.items()}
   ```
2. `name 'unicode' is not defined`

   Unicode is no longer a separate type in Python 3, the normal string type is already capable of unicode, so we just delete this case:

   ```
   elif isinstance(input, unicode):
       return input.encode('utf-8')
   ```
3. `'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'`

   To check whether a key exists in a dictionary, we use the `in` operator, so the `if` check becomes the following:

   ```
   if "media" in entities:
   ```

Afterwards, the code should run fine with Python 3.